# Take product of function handles within a cell and then evaluate for given values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, cells, function-handle

I have a cell of function handles and I would like to take the product of each row.

I then want to evaluate the function handles within the cell for certain values.

Example:

Original cell:

```
P{1,1} = @(x) x         P{1,2} = @(y) y
P{2,1} = @(x) x         P{2,2} = @(y) y.^2
```

Desired product:

```
P{1,1} = @(x,y) x.*y
P{2,1} = @(x,y) x.*y.`2
```

Then evaluate for

```
x = 2:0.1:3;
y = 1:0.1:2;
```

Then I suppose use `cell2mat` to get `P`?

I have been trying to use `cellfun`, but not sure if this is correct when using anonymous functions.

Would appreciate any advice!

Comment: This seems *really* over-complicated. I feel like there's a much better way to do this, but the examples here are probably much simpler than your actual problem. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape input vectors `x , y` to 3D  vectors and apply the function on them:

```
P{1,1} = @(x) x ;        P{1,2} = @(y) y;
P{2,1} = @(x) x  ;       P{2,2} = @(y) y.^2;
%reshape input to 3D
x=reshape(2:0.1:3,1,1,[]);
y=reshape(1:0.1:2,1,1,[]);
%empty cell of results
C = cell(size(P));
%apply functions of each column to the related input
C(:,1) = cellfun(@(f)f(x),P(:,1),'UniformOutput', false);
C(:,2) = cellfun(@(f)f(y),P(:,2),'UniformOutput', false);
%convert cell to an array
A = cell2mat(C);
%take product of each row
rowprod = prod(S,2)
%remove singleton dimensions
out = squeeze(rowprod)
```